# How to convert rows in columns in pandas python and perform operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this.

```
Date    Strike_price        value           
1/1/18      10000           55
1/1/18      10100           40
1/1/18      10200           37
1/1/18      10300           25  
2/1/18      10000           52
2/1/18      10100           38
2/1/18      10200           33
2/1/18      10300           21
3/1/18      10000           58
3/1/18      10100           43
3/1/18      10200           39
3/1/18      10300           26
```

I want to create a new dataframe from that like this:

```
1/1/18      27 # 27 == 55 - 40 + 37 - 25
2/1/18      26
3/1/18      28
```

I tried to use `df.pivot_table('value', ['Date'], 'Strike_Price')`, which converts strike prices into columns but then i am not able to delete or filter out any specific columns from DF.

Can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: I don't get why you add some and subtract others in your expected output.  Either way, this looks more like a `groupby` than a `pivot`

Comment: @user3483203 It depends on trader position. If he buy 2 and sell 2 strike price, then to get final amount I need to add 2 and subtract 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
>>> df
      Date  Strike_price  value
0   1/1/18         10000     55
1   1/1/18         10100     40
2   1/1/18         10200     37
3   1/1/18         10300     25
4   2/1/18         10000     52
5   2/1/18         10100     38
6   2/1/18         10200     33
7   2/1/18         10300     21
8   3/1/18         10000     58
9   3/1/18         10100     43
10  3/1/18         10200     39
11  3/1/18         10300     26
```

you can issue

```
>>> df.groupby('Date')['value'].agg(lambda s: s[::2].sum() - s[1::2].sum())
Date
1/1/18    27
2/1/18    26
3/1/18    28
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Alternatively, you might prefer

```
>>> df.groupby('Date', as_index=False)['value'].agg(lambda s: s[::2].sum() - s[1::2].sum())
     Date  value
0  1/1/18     27
1  2/1/18     26
2  3/1/18     28
```

Comment: Thanks timgeb. It works as expected. Appreciate your efforts. I have one more question on same line. Is that possible instead of s[1::2].sum() can we pass strike_price itself? Why i am asking is because I can write a more generic function.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal no problem. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "pass `strike_price` itself". The comment section is not really a good place to discuss follow up questions, but feel free to ask a new question (make sure to accurately explain what you need) and I will have a look at it.

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to multiply odd rows of your "value" by -1:

```
df.value.iloc[1::2] *= -1
```

Then do a groupby and sum:

```
df.groupby('Date').sum()
```

This worked for me. If you don't want to modify your original "value" column, you could make a new column, operate on it, then optionally remove that column at the end.

Comment: This doesn't account for different length groups (or odd length groups)